# Replacing text from string with an image using flask

Tags: python, flask

I have written a piece of code that matches if the string has anything of the pattern text.someExtension, In my case, it would be fileName.png in the string, converts it into an img tag and displays on the HTML file using python and flask. Let us take the example string: 
"What is the output of this program? e.png" 
the code matches e.png and it then replaces e.png by

```
"<br><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='pics/e.png')}}" /><br>"
```

The image e.png is put in the folder pics inside the static folder.
If this string is pushed into a flask variable even by adding Markup() to it it isn't rendering the image but showing the following output.

[output on html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61hBQ.jpg)

why is it so? Any way to make it display the image e.png?

my code is:

```
import re
from flask import Flask,  Markup, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

def rep(x):
    text = re.findall(r'\w+[.]\w+', x)
    for i in text:
        b ="<img src=\"{{ url_for('static',filename='pics/"+i+"')}}\">"
        x=x.replace(i,b)
    return x

@app.route('/')
def home():
    a = "What is the output of this program? e.png"
    a = rep(a)
    return render_template('new.html',var=Markup(a))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=8032)
```

And the HTML file is,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{var}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: At the moment I have no time to write an example but I'd start from this Emoji plugin for Flask, probably: https://github.com/sh4nks/flask-emoji/blob/master/flask_emoji/__init__.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the value you're passing to your template is a string and even though the string you're inserting is formatted with the {{ brackets, flask doesn't interpret those. Notice if you look at the html being served, it actually contains the string 'url_for'...

You're also not even importing the url_for function from flask, so that wouldn't have worked anyway.

The solution:

```
import re
from flask import Flask, url_for, Markup, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

def rep(x):
    text = re.findall(r'\w+[.]\w+', x)
    for i in text:
        b ="<img src='" + url_for('static', filename='pics/'+i) + "'>"
        x=x.replace(i,b)
    return x

@app.route('/')
def home():
    a = "What is the output of this program? e.png"
    a = rep(a)
    return render_template('new.html', var=Markup(a))

@app.route('/static/<path:path>')
def static_file(path):
    return send_from_directory('static', path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=8032)
```

The html file can remain unchanged. This solution

- separately tells the flask server to listen and serve the static files under the /static page.
- Creates the html with the image url by string concatenation, instead of trying to use template rendering.